# Evaluate the Limit of the Quotient of two exponential functions

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Say you have the following function:

$$\frac{a^x}{b^x}$$

and want to evaluate it's limit as $x$ approaches infinity. Intuition tells me that the limit will approach $0$ if $b > a$ and will approach $\infty$ if $a>b$ and plugging various equations into a graphing calculator bears this out.

However I am at a loss for how to definitively prove that this is the case. Is there a specific identity or theorem for evaluating such a limit?

Comment: It may help to think of it like this: $$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^x = r^x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1+x\le e^x \le \frac {1}{1-x}} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x<1$.

Noting that $\frac{a^x}{b^x}=e^{x\log(a/b)}$, application of $(1)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{1+x\log(a/b)\le \frac{a^x}{b^x}\le \frac{1}{1-x\log(a/b)} }\tag 2
\end{align}$$

for $x\log(a/b)<1$.

> If $a=b$, then we see that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a^x}{b^x}=1$.
>
> If $a>b$, then the left-hand side inequality yields $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a^x}{b^x}=\infty$.
>
> If $a<b$, then the right-hand side inequality yields $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a^x}{b^x}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

write it as:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^x=\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{x (\ln a-\ln b)}
$$

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. Much thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens when $a/b<1$? What about $a/b=1$? What about.....